# Getting vimeo access token using client and client secret on postman

Tags: javascript, vimeo, vimeo-player

i have client id and client secrete id i am having tough time getting access token using postman
they are asking foe redirect uri where i dont have one, somebody out there could you please help me out to solve this problem

Answer (score 0):

I was also struggling with the same, but some how repeated after looking at the documentation got to hit the API via Postman. Please have a look on the screenshots attached. You will get all the things in the [MyApp](https://developer.vimeo.com/apps) Page

1. In Headers - Add these parameters (token you need to generate on your App Page
   [Headers Type](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UVEaY.jpg)
2. Add this as raw in your Body (as shown in below image)

   {
   "grant_type": "client_credentials",
   "scope": "public"
   }
   [Body raw](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t573Z.jpg)